# URL and file system structure in php for a Image Website

Tags: php, internationalization

I want to build a image website like this

- ex.com/en-us/lion-wallpapers.html
- ex.com/en-gb/lion-wallpapers.html
- ex.com/en-in/lion-wallpapers.html

and i want to use single image path to be go through in multiple urls 
using routing

- images/lion/lion.jpg

.....is google only crawls single image with urls ???
or am i need to maintain individual directories and make them to copy on each directory?? so suggest me some best practises and URL srtructure for this ...

Answer (score 0):

For URL structure like this your better off using a framework that has support for routing and then building your website in a Model-View-Controller(MVC) pattern.

This is quite abstracted architectural stuff so I can't really give specific examples.

Any framework that supports routing would work but an example is Zend Framework: http://framework.zend.com/

Here's their documentation on routing: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

With routing you would be able to one lion-wallpapers.html page that then depending on the URL changes the language on the page.

In terms of how google will crawl your site, it will crawl your websites using links from your first page and anything you add to a sitemap. You can help customise how it crawls your website by adding your site to Google Webmaster tools here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en